# Question Regarding Statistically Significant Population Attributes

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, population

I have a problem I am trying to solve with the Chi Squared test, but I am starting to realize there are probably better methods to use, and I was looking for suggestions.

Say I have two independent populations X and Y made up of different males and females.

Population X >> Y, and they were drawn independently from the the "world" population.

I see that N_Y people in Y liked ice cream, and I want to see if this is statistically significant (or in english terms, normal or abnormal) looking at the larger population (looking at N_X, the number of people in a similar but larger population X that liked ice cream)

I think the chi squared test can be used for this but I am wondering what other approaches I should be looking at.

If this isnt clear, please let me know.

Comment: Do you have a sample from each population, or do you actually know the total number of people in each population who like ice cream?

Comment: I know the number of people

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know the number of people in each  population who like ice cream, then there is no need to perform a hypothesis test to determine whether or not the population proportions are different.. St.atistical significance has to do with whether or not you can infer from sample proportions whether or not the population proportions are different. In your case, you already know that the population proportions are different, the question now is of practical significance not statistical significance.